# Flex Application on IIS7

Tags: apache-flex, iis-7, windows-server-2008

I deployed my Flex Application to a Windows Server 2008 machine and it stoped working.
It runs fine on a Windows Server 2003 and on my local machine.

Details:
The application runs and loads the RSL libraries.
It shows the login screen.
I log in into it and it start showing the whole interface.
Suddenly the app screen gets empty and all the interface elements disappear

any clues?

Comment: I doubt this has anything to do with IIS; and if the app loads properly and lets you log in I doubt this has anything to do with RSLs.  What happens before your app gets empty?  Is it loading any SWFs on the fly?  Is it trying to access external domains?  Are crossdomain.xml files in place?  Are you using the same URL/domain in Windows Server 2003 vs 2008?  If not; do you have any hard coded URLs in place? Are you using AMF? IS a gateway setup properly on the 2008 server?